Can someone tell me why my javascript higher-order function won't work as intended?
This is my code, and for some reason, whenever I put in a value less than 4, I get array with 5 elements instead of 3. What could I be doing wrong? Javascript isn't returning that there is an error in the code.
let actionPlan = ['1. Oatmeal bath',
    '2. Drink 16 oz water',
    '3. Put on 100% cotton shorts',
    '4. Butterfly pose',
    '5. Pigeon Pose',
    '6. Lidocaine gel',
    '7. 200 mg pyridium'
];


function painManagement (painLevel) {
    if (painLevel >= 7) {
        return function () {
            return actionPlan;
        }
    } else if (3 < painLevel < 7) {
        return function () {
            return actionPlan.slice(0,5);
        }
    } else if (0 < painLevel < 4) {
        return function () {
            return actionPlan.slice(0,3);
        }
    } else if (painLevel === 0) {
        return 'Hooray, no pain!';
    }
}

console.log(painManagement(2)());

//Output (5) ['1. Oatmeal bath', '2. Drink 16 oz water', '3. Put on 100% cotton shorts', '4. Butterfly pose', '5. Pigeon Pose']


(3 < painLevel < 7) is not JavaScript syntax for what you're trying to do. You want (3 < painlevel && painlevel < 7)

you should also probably try to be consistent with your return types, like return function() { return "Hooray, no pain!"; } (or even more consistent, an empty array return function() { return []; }), that way there's not a runtime error when ran like painManagement(0)() especially if that 0 comes in from a variable or user input of some kind

@Samathingamajig Thanks! That also helped solve my problem if someone put in 0
